# Which kind of network should i choose to setup a Satndalone Spark Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, networking, virtual-machine

I have 2 PC (with Windows as default OS), let's say PC_master and PC_slave. Since it is recommended to work with Linux to manage a spark Cluster i created one Virtual Machines with Linux on each of theses PC: VM_master on PC_master and VM_slave on PC_slave.

I would like to setup a Standalone Spark Cluster, so  which Networking configuration should i use (NAT, Bridge, HostOnly?) for theses 2VM in order that they own their private IP adress letting me ssh from one to another without the need of port forwarding ?

Edit: My two laptop are linked to the same box, so they have private IP and supposed to be linked to the same router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it seems that if i want to give each VM its own Ip adress to create a private Network i have to choose Bridge Network which will assign a unique Ip for each VM!